# What is multilooking?

Tags: remote-sensing, radar

Today I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sDSLD5y_Cmc) on youtube for multilooking the data with NEST (Next ESA SAR Toolbox) and it seems that it produces square pixel out of rectangular SAR pixels.

**Does it operate as simply as averaging several pixels or it has a more complicated algorithm?**

I haven't been able to find a resource which illustrates the algorithm as simply as possible but comprehensively.

Comment: From the [Tour] you will see that there should be only one question per question for our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: @PolyGeo I will remove the last question but the first 3 questions are almost the same. what does multilooking do and a resource for its algorithm

Comment: @PolyGeo Now it's not too broad . It's only about a specific algorithm

Comment: @sepideh, asking too many questions in one post attracts too many answers which is not fit with SE etiquette. Please ask the three question separately in three distinct post.

Comment: The first is superfluous - try "Does it operate as simply as ...?  The last can be a statement - "I have not been able to find a resource to study."

Comment: @PolyGeo Is it ok?

Answer (score 7):

There are many multi-look algorithms. At the most basic, the process reduces noise (or "speckle") in SAR images by averaging adjacent pixels. Often SAR processors allow the user to define some N x N window over which to average. However, other algorithms include using median values rather than mean values. For a comparison of other algorithms, see ["Performance evaluation of several adaptive speckle filters for SAR imaging."](http://marte.sid.inpe.br/col/dpi.inpe.br/sbsr@80/2008/11.18.12.44/doc/7299-7305.pdf)

The overall effect of multi-look algorithms is to reduce the standard deviation of the noise level and force a more Gaussian distribution of noise in the SAR image at the cost of decreased resolution.